# AS3 which item in an array has the lower value?

Tags: actionscript-3

I’m trying to make a game like tower defence in AS3 and currently cant find solution to check which item in an array has the lower value of distance between enemy and turret, in order to choose which enemy to attack first.

I'm really stuck with this problem and asking for your help.

Here is a short code:

```
var enemyArray:Array = new Array();
var turretArray:Array = new Array();

addEventListener(Event.EnterFrame, loop);

// adding enemies
for(var i:int=0; i<3; i++){
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
    ...
    ...
    enemyArray.push(enemy);
    addChild(enemy);
}

// adding turret
for(var t:int=0; t<2; t++){
    var turret:Turret = new Turret();
    ...
    ...
    turret.destinationX = 0;
    turret.destinationY = 0;
    turret.distance = 0;
    turretArray.push(turret);
    addChild(turret);
}

// loop
function loop(event:Event):void{
    for(var j:int=enemyArray.length-1; j>=0; j--){
        for(var k:int=turretArray.length-1; k>=0; k--){

            // getting destination
            turretArray[k].destinationX = turretArray[k].x - enemyArray[j].x;
            turretArray[k].destinationY = turretArray[k].y - enemyArray[j].y;

            // getting distance between turret and enemy
            turretArray[k].distance =   Math.sqrt(turretArray[k].destinationX*turretArray[k].destinationX+turretArray[k].destinationY*turretArray[k].destinationY);

            // here i need to get min value from all turrets distance
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to be keeping track of the lowest value you've found as you go rather than overwriting it every time (if I've understood your code, correctly).

```
// loop
function loop(event:Event):void{
    for(var k:int=turretArray.length-1; k>=0; k--)
    {
        turretArray[k].distance = -1;

        for(var j:int=enemyArray.length-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            var dx = turretArray[k].x - enemyArray[j].x;
            var dy = turretArray[k].y - enemyArray[j].y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if(dist < turretArray[k].distance || turretArray[k].distance < 0)
            {
                turretArray[k].distance = dist;
                turretArray[k].destinationX = dx;
                turretArray[k].destinationY = dy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we store the initial distance value found in `turretArray[k].distance`, and only overwrite that if we find a lower one.  We set it to `-1` each time so we can tell if it's been set, yet, or not.

Comment: (_psst: select this as the answer!_)

Answer (score 0):

This is the equation you want:

http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html

sqrt( (turret1X - turret2x)^2 + (turret1Y - turret2Y)^2 )

Comment: If you just want to determine the shortest distance, you don't really need to compute the square root. The minimum square of the distance will belong to the minimum distance.